# S3 boto3 corrupts file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the following function:

```
def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket -> from aws docs

    :param file_name: File to upload
    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    # Upload the file
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```

I am trying to upload a html file to an S3 bucket acting as a webserver. When I manually upload the html file to S3, it works as expected, and displays the page when I navigate to the S3 bucket's URL.

If I programmatically upload the file using the above function, the html file will no longer be hosted, and my browser will attempt to download a XZ file.

Am I missing a parameter or something?

Comment: Your code is actually the [sample boto3 code](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html) verbatim. Consider setting the relevant ContentType in ExtraArgs.

Comment: @jarmod That did it! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of @jarmod, I learned I was setting an incorrect content-type.

Here is the updated function to upload an HTML file as text/html.

```
def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket -> from aws docs

    :param file_name: File to upload
    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    # Upload the file
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': "text/html"})
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```